# Update or Insert a new value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following SQL command in asp.net:

```
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userscore (username, score)VALUES(@username,   @score)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", userscore);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This command works but it stores two values in the my sql database every button click. It gets the score value from the textbox, but when an username + a score is in the database already, I want to update the value. Can someone help me with a query to get this done?

To clarify my question: I want to store the new score even when it's lower then the current score, and the username is unique in the table.

Comment: what database SQL Server?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to only store the new value if it is higher than the old one OR store the new value regardless?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you only want to store one highscore per username, rather than only one global highscore.

```
DECLARE @highscore int NULL
SELECT @highscore = MAX(score) FROM userscore WHERE username = @username

IF @highscore IS NULL BEGIN

    INSERT INTO userscore ( username, score ) VALUES ( @username, @score )

END ELSE IF @score > @highscore BEGIN

    UPDATE userscore SET score = @score WHERE username = @username

END
```

This T-SQL script requires two parameters, `@username` and `@score`. The `@highscore` variale is declared within the script.

Answer (score 2):

If SQL 2008 or above:

```
MERGE INTO userscore as target
  USING(VALUES(@username, @score)) AS source(UserName, Score)
  ON (target.UserName = source.UserName)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Score = source.Score)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(UserName, Score) VALUES(source.UserName, source.Score)
;
```

The `MERGE` statement performs an update if a matching record exists or an insert if it doesn't.  It's all one statement as well so you don't have to check for existence of the record first.

A copy/paste version is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "MERGE INTO userscore as target USING(VALUES(@username, @score)) AS Source(UserName, Score) ON (target.UserName = source.UserName) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Score = source.Score) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(UserName, Score) VALUES(source.UserName, source.Score);";
```

Comment: Your SQL doesn't compare `@score` against the user's current highscore so it will only log the most recent score, not the highest.

Comment: @Dai: yeah, I know.  The meaning of the question text was different from the title.  I asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Dai: apparently he doesn't want the highest, just the last one.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a stored procedure that inserts the score if there is no score or updates the user's score if it's lower than the new score

code

```cs
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "update_highscore";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", userscore);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

execute this to create a stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_highscore
@username VARCHAR(30),
@userscore INT
AS
UPDATE userscore 
SET score = @score
WHERE username = @username

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT userscore (username, score) VALUES (@username, @score)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the username is supposed to be unique for the table, then you can use an update query plus SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userscore SET score = @score WHERE username = @username";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", userscore);
var numRowsAffected cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(numRowsAffected == 0)
{
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userscore (username, score)VALUES(@username,   @score)";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OPs requirement of only keeping the highest score.  This would just keep the most recent score in the database.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Per the OP, he doesn't actually want the highest, just the latest.